# Relationship between surface area and rate of reaction

Tags: acid-base

Say I add a whole piece of calcium carbonate to some $\ce{HCl}$ and then measure the reaction rate by measuring how quickly the mass changes (how quickly $\ce{CO2}$ is being evolved).

Then, I repeat the experiment for the same size calcium carbonate piece but broken into 2 pieces, then 4 pieces and finally, 6 pieces. If I plot the rate of reaction vs. the surface area of the calcium carbonate, would I get a linear relationship?

Comment: You mean *initial* rate? I don't think you could measure it quickly enough.

Comment: Yes, initial rate. So, let's say the grams evolved over 120s